# Python reduce sum tuple

Tags: python

I have an input that will vary in size.

```
data = [(("101","A"),5), (("105","C"),12), (("101", "B"),4)]
```

Looking for an output that groups by key[0], keeps all items of key[1]. And, sums up the values.

```
output = [(("101", "A", "B"),9), (("105", "C"),12)]
```

I've tried.

```
my_dict = dict(data)
final_values = {}
for k,v in my_dict.items():
    key1 = k[0]
    key2 = k[1]

    if key1 not in final_values:
        final_values[key1] = []
    final_values[key1].append(key2)
    final_values[key1].append(v)
```

Which returns.

```
{'101': ['A', 5, 'B', 4], '105': ['C', 12]}
```

I'd like to get the sum of the numbers in the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using a [`collections.defaultdict()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to group the items, then flattening the results at the end:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from operator import itemgetter

data = [(("101","A"),5), (("105","C"),12), (("101", "B"),4)]

d = defaultdict(list)
for (x, y), z in data:
    d[x].append((y, z))

result = [
    ((k, *tuple(map(itemgetter(0), v))), sum(map(itemgetter(1), v)))
    for k, v in d.items()
]
print(result)
# [(('101', 'A', 'B'), 9), (('105', 'C'), 12)]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
for k in final_values:
    print '%s: sum is %d' % (k, sum([x for x in final_values[k] if type(x) is int]))
```